# Compare get values with one of the value of fields from database

Tags: php

Consider a demo url like this:www.example.com/act/yes?user_id=125

I know that a hacker or other will try to change the digit value in url.

My question is how can we compare that get value from url with one of the field's value in yes(www.example.com/act/yes) page so that only entries with that get value should be displayed in PHP?

I tried this in if condition

```
if($_GET['user_id'] == $result[0]->user_id)
{
    show db values
}
else
{
    show nothing
}
```

where `$result= $this->model->edityes($_GET['user_id']);`

$result will contain array containing all fields data containing id $_GET['user_id'].

Comment: Not really clear... Where is applied and what returns `$result= $this->model->edityes($_GET['user_id']);`

Comment: @zeflex,i am putting the value obtained as $_GET['user_id'](here 125) as a argument to model's function which will bring all record with id 125.

Comment: In this case why do you use a if instruction like yours. Why don't you compare if you have a $result as you are sending the $_GET['user_id'] to the model. If $results returns false, then show nothing.

Answer (score 1):

All that matters in this equation is that the value of  the $_GET string is always sanitized before being passed to the database. In your case user_id seems to always be an integer, so for you it's as simple as:

```
$user_id = (isset($_GET['user_id']) && is_int($_GET['user_id'])) ? $_GET['user_id'] : false;
if($user_id){

} else {

}
```

In the above we're simply checking if the user_id param exists (?user_id=) and if it's of type int (a whole number).

Meanwhile if using prepared statements, you can just pass the value along and rest easily.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select * from users where user_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['user_id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

In this way, we allow the mysqli driver to handle the sanitizing of the data for us, as we've told it that the bound parameter `$_GET['user_id']` must be an integer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this->model->edityes((int)$_GET['user_id']);
if ($result) {
// do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```